# Update an aggregate table with information from another table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an aggregate table that needs to be updated frequently from a table that is generated by new data every few hours. Since
the aggregate table grows a lot every update, I need an efficient way to update the aggregate table.
Can someone please show me how to merge information from a new table to an aggregate table as shown below?

For example

```
val aggregate_table = Seq(("A", 10),("B", 20),("C", 30),("D", 40)).toDF("id", "total")
| id  | total |
|-----+-------|
| "A" |    10 |
| "B" |    20 |
| "C" |    30 |
| "D" |    40 |

val new_info_table = Seq(("X"),("B"),("C"),("B"),("A"),("A"),("C"),("B")).toDF("id")
| id  |
|-----|
| "X" |
| "B" |
| "C" |
| "B" |
| "A" |
| "A" |
| "C" |
| "B" |
```

Resulting aggregate_table after aggregate_table has been merged with 
new_info_table

```
 aggregate_table
| id  | total |
|-----+-------|
| "A" |    12 |
| "B" |    23 |
| "C" |    33 |
| "D" |    40 |
| "X" |     1 |
```

Comment: Aggregate and outer join... But overall description sounds like a job for structured streaming with complete output mode.

Comment: @user8371915, structured streaming looks really interesting. Thanks for recommending this.

Comment: Below is some code I wrote the perform the tasks as @user8371915 instructed. For future reference.

`val info_table_formated = new_info_table.groupBy("id").agg(count("id").alias("total"))
val new_aggregate_table = aggregate_table.union(info_table_formated).groupBy("id").agg(sum("total").alias("total"))`